# Pass-through API / Preserve backend headers in Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am building an application to call a back-end which responds with a mime-type response.

```
@Override
public Mono<String> getDocument() {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri(path)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
}
```

From this request, I need to preserve the response headers and pass it through as the response. This is mostly because the response headers contain the dynamic content type of the file. I need to forward these headers (all as received) to the API response. For example :

```
Content-Type : application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.pdf"
```

Following is my handler.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getDocument(ServerRequest request) {
        return ServerResponse
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.pdf\"")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(documentService.getDocument(), String.class));
    }
```

The file is coming through from the API as an attachment as expected, but I do not want to hard code the content-type header. How can I achieve this?

Update with the handler code :

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getDocument(ServerRequest request) {
     return ServerResponse
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(documentService.getDocument(), String.class));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by returning a ResponseEntity from the service instead of the body and using that to construct the ServerResponse in the handler.

Service :

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> getDocument() {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri(path)
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(String.class);
}
```

Handler :

```
   public Mono<ServerResponse> getDocument(ServerRequest request) {
        return documentService
                .getDocument()
                .flatMap(r -> ServerResponse
                        .ok()
                        .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(r.getHeaders()))
                        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(r.getBody()))
                );
    }
```